# how split if statement over multiple lines in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Im trying to format my yml to be more readable.
I have an if statement that is really long with a bunch of and/ors and I would like to be able to spread it across multiple lines
So something along the lines of

```
{{-if or
   (eq 'abc' .values.foo)
   (eq 'def' . values.bar)
}}
Def:'works'
{{- end}}
```

But this throws up errors for incomplete if statement.
Is there some special character or syntax I can use to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

helm supports direct line breaks without special characters.

Missing a space between `{{` and `if`.

There is an extra space between `.` and `values`.

String constants require double quotes.

demo:

values.yaml

```yaml
foo: xxx
bar: yyy
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    {{- include "test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data: 
  cfg: |-
    {{- if or
      (eq "abc" .Values.foo)
      (eq "def" .Values.bar)
    }}
    if
    {{- else }}
    else
    {{- end }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  cfg: |-
    else
```